# Need specific word between two special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this URL in input, and I need to be required output which has given below.

**Input** : "http://localhost:3000/prospects/talk-to-your-sphere"

**Output**: ["/prospects", "/talk-to-your-sphere"]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried using regex match?

Comment: No, I tried with the split() method but it didn't work expectedly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, maybe we can help.

Comment: Please clearly state what you want to achieve, and what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain you clearly, please check my question again I have to edit it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Input : http://localhost:3000/prospects/talk-to-your-sphere
// Output: ["/prospects", "/talk-to-your-sphere"]

const input = 'http://localhost:3000/prospects/talk-to-your-sphere'
let output = input.split('/').filter((member) => member) // .filter to get rid of the empty strings
output.shift() // remove http:
output.shift() // remove localhost:3000
output = output.map((member) => '/' + member)

console.log(output) // ["/prospects", "/talk-to-your-sphere"]
```